# Invalid system call interception in Linux kernel

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel

I want to use interception of **open** system call. Since my kernel version is 4.18, I should take an address of system call table from **System.map** file in **/boot** folder. So,

```
grep sys_call_table System.map-4.18.0-10-generic
```

gives me following strings:

```
ffffffff81e001c0 R sys_call_table
ffffffff81e015a0 R ia32_sys_call_table
```

I use this address (from first string) in my code, but **insmod** returns "Killed" after .ko execution.

I have no idea 'bout this, your tips will help me a lot!

```
unsigned long *sys_call_table = (unsigned long *)0xffffffff81e001c0; 

asmlinkage int (*original_call) (const char *, int, int);

asmlinkage int our_sys_open(const char *filename, int flags, int mode)
{
  int i = 0;
  char ch;
    do {
      get_user(ch, filename + i);
      i++;
      printk("%c", ch);
    } while (ch != 0);
    printk("\n");
  return original_call(filename, flags, mode);
}

int init_module()
{
  original_call = (void *) sys_call_table[__NR_open];
  sys_call_table[__NR_open] = (unsigned long) our_sys_open;
  return 0;
}
void cleanup_module()
{
  sys_call_table[__NR_open] = original_call;
}

MODULE_LICENSE("GPL");
```

Comment: I'm no expert kernel hacker, but I wonder if the syscall table is mapped read-only. It might not be possible to overwrite entries.

Comment: You module has no init.

Comment: Kamil, what's about init_module()?

Comment: I think @davmac is right - you might want to look at: https://lwn.net/Articles/517475/